# Loop fade in and out on video using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fade in on a video once it starts, fade out once it has ended and restart after, but I cant seem to get the right result.

Here is what I have to far:

```
var video = $('.central-video-wrapper video');

video.on('ended', function() {
    video.fadeOut('slow');
    video.load( function(){
        video.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *and restart after*? Fade out when end and then restart video and fade in?

Comment: Basically fade in once the page loads and fade out once the video ends and also loops.

Comment: Your code work on end. http://jsfiddle.net/q23dgthx/

Comment: Any errors? what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Well yeah but it doesnt restart the video after the fade out. :)

Comment: Use `loop` attribute in `video` tag

Comment: Well im using a wordpress plugin which allows me to enable looping on the video, but once I do that, the fadeout doesnt work anymore.

Comment: @GiurgiteanuPaulMihai The `loop` attribute cause video played instantly after end. So you have `fadeIn` instantly after `fadeOut`

Comment: I might have explained myself wrong. The fade out has to happen before the video ends and the fade in on start. 

Do I have to add some kind of delay? or how would I be able to make so that it fades out before video ends?

I have tried doing this using only css but it desyncs after a few loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `play` and `ended` event for your purpose and in event handler use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```
var video = $('.central-video-wrapper video');
video.on('play', function() {
  video.fadeIn('slow');
}).on('ended', function() {
  video.fadeOut('slow');
});
```

But if you want to `fadeOut` video `onend` and then `fadeIn` it and play it again, you can use `setTimeout()` and in it function use `.play()` to playing video.

```
var video = $('.central-video-wrapper video');
video.on('play', function() {
  video.fadeIn('slow');
}).on('ended', function() {
  video.fadeOut('slow');
  setTimeout(function(){
    video[0].duration = 0;
    video[0].play();
  }, 1000)
});
```

Check result in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLra95h2/)

Comment: The second code is definitely what im looking for. However I get "Cannot assign to read only property 'duration' of object '#<HTMLVideoElement>" once the video ends and also the fade in does not happen when page loads.

Comment: Once the video ends I get "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'duration' of object '#<HTMLVideoElement>'" . The fade in and out works alright :) but the loop doesnt happen. :(

Comment: @GiurgiteanuPaulMihai So remove `video[0].duration = 0;` part of code, Video played from first automatically

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much ! You saved me hours of attempting hours of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in callback function

```
video.on('ended', function() {
    video.fadeOut('slow',function(){
       video.load( function(){
           video.fadeIn('slow');
       });

    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and i got "Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function".
I did change video.load(function() {  to video.on('load', function() { 
which fixed the error but the looping still doesnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it

**HTML**

```
<video id="background-video" autoplay muted>
  <source src="./video/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const video = document.querySelector("#background-video");
let one_uttered = 0;
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    let remainingTime = (video.duration - video.currentTime); // decimals
    if (Math.floor(remainingTime) === 1) { // round it
        one_uttered++;
        if (one_uttered === 1) { // fade out when 1000 millisec remained
            $("#background-video").fadeOut(1000); //adds opacity 0 and display to none
        }
    }
    one_uttered = 0; //reset to fadeOut in the next loop
});
video.onended = (event) => {
    // display to block quickly. Alternatively using css({"display":"block"}) can do the job as well
    $("#background-video").fadeIn(1, function() { 
        video.play();
        // quickly fadeout to apply fadeIn effect 
        $("#background-video").fadeOut(1, function() {
            // and start fadeIn from fresh here
            $("#background-video").fadeIn(1000); 
        }); 
    }); 
};
```